# Как вывести значение одного цикла в другом?

Tags: php

Как сделать, чтобы значение `$result_1` можно было вывести в `<input type="(тут)">` внутри данного кода: 
`foreach ($acc as $acc_result){ echo '<label><input type="checkbox">'.$acc_result.'</label>';}`?

```html
<?php                   
$fieldValues = $ObjectField_name->field_name0->namer_ff;


$fieldTexts_2 = array_reduce((array)$fieldValues, function ($acc_2, $valueData_2) {
 
    if (!empty($valueData_2->test_list)) {
        $acc_2[] = trim($valueData_2->test_list);
    }
    
    foreach ($acc_2 as $acc_result_2){
        $result_1 = $acc_result_2;
    }
    
});

$fieldTexts = array_reduce((array)$fieldValues, function ($acc, $valueData) {
 
    if (!empty($valueData->test_text)) {
        $acc[] = trim($valueData->test_text);
    }
    
    foreach ($acc as $acc_result){
        echo '<label><input type="checkbox">'.$acc_result.'</label>';
    }
    
});

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если правильно вас понял

```
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
    $array["test_key_".$i] = "test_".$i;
}
              
foreach( $array as $key => $value ){
    echo $key."\t=>\t".$value."\n";
}
```